# How to add image in object key value with paragraph in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, image, dom, javascript-objects, dom-manipulation

Basically, the webpage has content in two languages that's why i want to pass image with paragraph from JavaScript object.But it is showing me [object HTMLImageElement] instead of image.

html:

```
  <p id="ourvisioncardparagraph" >
   // Here the image will appear with paragraph tag
  </p>
```

js:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src ="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1664575198308-3959904fa430?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80";
img.alt = "star"

var data = {
  english: {
    ourvisioncardparagraph: `To reinvent finance through innovation & technology ${img} making 
      it convenient, accessible & fair to all.`
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `img.outerHTML` to get an elements html. So all in all:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src ="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1664575198308-3959904fa430?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80";
img.alt = "star";

var data = {
  english: {
  ourvisioncardparagraph: `To reinvent finance through innovation & technology ${img.outerHTML} making  it convenient, accessible & fair to all.`
    }
}

document.getElementById("ourvisioncardparagraph").innerHTML = data.english.ourvisioncardparagraph;
```

Comment: Cool it works !! Johan how can i add the width of an image is there a way ?

Comment: You can use the image constructor to add width and height: new Image(width, height)

Alternatively you can add a class: img.className = "image-class" and then some css to that class